# Should I be using MySQL Cluster, Master to Master replication, or something else?

Tags: mysql

I started just using a solo MySQL server and moved on to using Master to Slave replication.  This is all inside our network.  I have a cloud application where customers post orders to our system.  When our ISP goes down it's a nightmare.

I'm looking to have one server on-site and one server off-site that can be in sync and if the one goes down the other one can take over and not miss a step.  I have my DNS failover in place and 2 web servers, but I can't decide what I need to do for the MySQL servers.

I don't mind putting in the work to learn MySQL cluster, but I'm not sure if that is the correct solution or master to master or something else?

Scale:  I have an orders table currently sitting at 150,000 rows and that could grow to 500,000 this year and possibly start getting into the millions over the next couple years.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I never had any formal schooling on the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered hosting somewhere with better uptime?

Comment: We currently host internally because the software is part of a bigger software package.  Do you think if I separated it out and went with a company like linode that would be enough for me to not have to worry about it going down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest way - just place your server in some reliable datacenter. This way you can reduce failure rate to be tolerable to be handled semi-manually with a master-slave configuration.

If you need to host on-site - then look into improving your site's connectivity, like all datacenters do - have backup ISP channels, with own AS(ip autonomous system) and BGP routing - so when one ISP fails - even ips stay the same, traffic just balances to the others.

Mysql server does not support master-master replication, only mysql cluster supports multi-master, so in fact if you need fast failover - question is whether to host it yourself or use DBaaS (database-as-a-service, folks like cleardb).

DBaaS with SLA and failover is quite expensive, also adds some network delays because your own app and db servers groups most probably are in the same datacenters. But on the plus side - they are easier and faster to setup.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  I'm going to go with multiple ISPs and try to get better reliability that way.